# CMAKE 3.16 Can't fine Visual Studio Instance

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a cmake project that uses VC 2017 Pro. I have used this cmake successfully in the past. Now back to working on the project and when I bring up cmake-gui and click Configure I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:99 (enable_language):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 15 2017

  could not find specified instance of Visual Studio:

    D:/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/OpenCV/OpenCV/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/OpenCV/OpenCV/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Note that the directory listed above for VS is correct. I have looked at many posts and checked everything I can find that seems to relate to this problem but no joy. I have used procmon to examine the registry and file accesses by cmake when I click configure but no clues have emerged.

Cmake seems to know the path to VS and the cmakelists.txt cmakecache.txt and cmakevars.txt files all have correct paths as best I can determine. I have checked for files that need to be present and directory permissions...everything I can think of but no luck.

Finally, the cmakeerror.log and cmakeoutput.log files are not modified by running the configure which may be normal for this error but seems odd.

I am not a regular user of cmake but when I set up my project about 3 months ago, I was able to generate the project and VS compiled it successfully. I have no clue what changed as no changes to cmake or VS in the time since then.

Pulling my hair out...

Comment: Sounds like your configuration is out-of-date or stale. I would suggest deleting the CMakeCache.txt file from your build folder, and running CMake from scratch again.

Comment: That did not help. In fact, the CMakeCache.txt is now quite incomplete. I should have mentioned earlier that this the opencv project though I'm not sure how that would bear on the problem. enable_language is making some sort of check to verify the VS installation and failing.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that my instance of VS 2017 thought it had an update in progress. This may have been left over from an earlier update attempt that did not have enough disk space to complete. I though I had cancelled that update and was out clean but VS installer flagged my instance as "update in progress" and I was unaware of this. Now vswhere worked and VS itself worked just fine but whatever process cmake does to locate the VS instance failed due to this "in progress" state. I restarted the VS update which completed successfully and after that cmake was happy.